# Is there a common library for key listener for Java?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I'm making a game engine which supports Swing and JavaFX at the same time.

I provided key listener APIs like this:

#### Swing

```
fun addKeyListener(
    typed: Consumer<KeyEvent>? = null,
    pressed: Consumer<KeyEvent>? = null,
    released: Consumer<KeyEvent>? = null) {
    addKeyListener(object : KeyListener {
        override fun keyTyped(e: KeyEvent) {
            typed?.accept(e)
        }

        ... // Something similar for release and press
    })
}

fun addKeyTypedEvent(keyCode: Int, key: Consumer<KeyEvent>)
    = addKeyListener(typed = Consumer { e ->
            if (e.keyCode == keyCode) key.accept(e) })

... // Something similar for release and press
```

#### JavaFX

```
var onKeyTyepd: EventHandler<in KeyEvent>
    get() = scene.onKeyTyped
    set(value) {
        scene.onKeyTyped = value
    }

... // Something similar for release and press
```

But I want to extract an abstract common API to reduce the cost of migrating between Swing and JavaFX.
Since Swing and JavaFX uses different `KeyEvent`, I currently have no idea.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Why not make a wrapper/adapter?

Comment: @Bálint That will be my last solution if there's no common lib

Comment: Maybe both use AWT keyEvents underneath, otherwise you'll have to be creative I guess...